# running flutter app on iPhone with no internet does not work because the phone cant verify user without internet

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, ios16

As the title suggests the app is not opening up without internet because it needs to verify the developer (which is me). I also cant open it after killing the application without running it from my mac.

Is there any way to make this proccess smoother? I would like to be able to open application without reinstalling it everytime from my mac. I would also like to run the app without internet.

I need to be able to do this to test the offline mode on my application.

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: How do you install your app on your phone and which what certificate?

Comment: I have my own developer account which signed the app and which i approved on my phone. I run it from vscode. When i turn off the internet on iPhone the app wont run because "it cant verify developer without internet"

Comment: Can you look at this thread https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/697226 ?

Comment: You need to create a signed build and distribute it via something like TestFlight or Firebase app distribution.